# I can't drop the job that I dragged onto the calendar table with Alpine.js

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

i created a calendar with javascript. I want to add jobs to that calendar. I can drag the jobs but I cant drop it into the calendar.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQEI8.png)

body

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <div>
        <h4 x-data="{ message: 'Planlama Sistemi ❤️' }" x-text="message"></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="drag-and-drop" x-data="{ adding: false, removing: false }">
            <p>Bugün: <span id="bugun_get"></span></p>
            <ul x-on:dragover.prevent="adding = true" x-on:dragleave="adding = false" x-on:drop.prevent="adding = false; onDrop(event)">
                <li x-on:dragstart="draggedItem = event.target" x-on:dragend="draggedItem = null" draggable="true" :class="{ 'dragged': draggedItem === event.target }">
                    <p x-data="{ message: 'Su İç ❤️' }" x-text="message"></p>
                </li>
                <li x-on:dragstart="draggedItem = event.target" x-on:dragend="draggedItem = null" draggable="true" :class="{ 'dragged': draggedItem === event.target }">
                    <p x-data="{ message: 'Yemek Ye ❤️' }" x-text="message"></p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
<div>


<table id="takvim"  x-on:dragover.prevent="adding = true" x-on:dragleave="adding = false" x-on:drop.prevent="adding = false; onDrop(event)"></table>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <h4 x-data="{ message: 'Planlama Sistemi ❤️' }" x-text="message"></h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

javascript for drop event. it doesnt work.

```
function onDrop(event) {
    const target = event.target;
        if (target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'table') {
            target.appendChild(draggedItem);
        }
}
```

javascript for table. im taking automatically week days and month dates. its working fine.

```
moment.updateLocale('tr', {
        weekdays: ['Pazartesi', 'Salı', 'Çarşamba', 'Perşembe', 'Cuma', 'Cumartesi', 'Pazar'],
        week: {
          dow: 1, // Pazartesi günü haftanın başı
        },
      });


      var takvim_set = document.getElementById('takvim');
      // Haftanın günlerini birinci satıra ekle
      var gunler_set = moment.weekdays().map(function (gun) {
          return "<td>" + gun + "</td>";
      }).join("");
      takvim_set.innerHTML += "<tr>" + gunler_set + "</tr>";

          // Tarih aralığında döngü
          var row_set = "<tr>";
          var h_ilkgun = moment().startOf('week');
          var a_songun = moment("2023-12-31");

        while (h_ilkgun.isBefore(a_songun)) {
            for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                var aylik_set = h_ilkgun.format("DD");

                // Pazar gününü sona al
                if (h_ilkgun.day() === 0) {
                  row_set += "<td>" + aylik_set + "</td></tr><tr>";
                }else {
                    var cellClass = '';

                    if (h_ilkgun.isSameOrBefore(moment(), 'day')) {
                        cellClass = h_ilkgun.isSame(moment(), 'day') ? 'current-day' : 'past-day';
                    }
                       row_set += "<td class='" + cellClass + "'>" + aylik_set + "</td>";
                }

                h_ilkgun.add(1, 'days');
            }
        }
        row_set += "</tr>";
        takvim_set.innerHTML += row_set;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
//drag and drop fonksiyonu
function onDrop(event) {
  const target = event.target;
  if (target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'td') {
    target.appendChild(draggedItem);
  }
}

//draglenecek elementleri seç
var draggables = document.querySelectorAll('ul.gorev-listesi li');

draggables.forEach(function(draggableItem) {
  draggableItem.setAttribute('draggable', true);

  //dragle
  draggableItem.addEventListener('dragstart', function (event) {
    event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', '');
    draggedItem = event.target;
  });
});

//dropla
takvim_set.addEventListener('drop', onDrop);
takvim_set.addEventListener('dragover', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Please add some words of explenation...only code will not help others.